# Why the SOAP request has been accepted from SoapUI without configuring trust-store location?

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, soap, soapui

I built a Web-Service application in `Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7` and deployed it on `weblogic 10.3.6` with all Key-store and SSL configuration.

***SSl Configuration:***

**Use Server Certs :** Checked

**Two Way Client Cert Behavior:** Client Certs Not Requested. [That is means it is one-way ssl. 
Correct me if that wrong]

**SSL Listen Port Enabled:** Checked

***Key-store Configuration:***

**Custom Identity and Custom Trust.** The file path has been specified for those custom key store

A sample client application has been created and everything seems to be fine; I mean the client can not access the server application without specifying the trust store file location where the server certificate is stored and it is trusted at the client end.

By the server certificate I mean the same certificate that has been configured in server Key-store Configuration

for your information the client application referring to trust store as follow:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",[Trust-store location goes here]);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", [password goes here]);
```

Till now nothing wrong. Next is the problem details:

For the purpose of testing I tried to access the deployed web-service application using the SoapUI (open source software). What is confusing is the request has been sent, accepted at the server and proceed without specifying any thing for server certificate nor trust store location in `SoapUI` project configuration !!

**Why the SOAP request has been accepted from `SoapUI` without referring to server certificate? The request should be rejected in this case.**

Comment: For a helpful discussion about the issue, refer to the this: [Why the SOAP request has been accepted from SoapUI without configuring trust-store location?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3605237)

Answer (score 0):

My experience with SoapUI is that it is quite lenient.  For example, if it doesn't check if the CN of server certificate matches the fully qualified domain name in the URL.  In your case, your server most likely uses a CA signed certificate.  Most of the root and intermediate certificates of well known CA's (e.g. VeriSign/Symantec) are already included in the default truststores for most systems.  If your server had used a self-signed certificate, then SoapUI would have incurred SSL error unless you import the self-signed certificates into the truststore of the host where SoapUI is running.